# get href of clicked link with image inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I'm simply trying to get the `href` of the `a` when the mouse clicks the image or the surrounding area.

**HTML template:**

```
<nav id="main_nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/" data-path>
        <img class="dashboard_icon" src="img/icons/nav/dashboard.svg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ... more nav options
</nav>
```

**Styles:**

```
li { list-style: none; display: block; width: 80px; height: 80px; }
a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
img { width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: 25px; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-path]', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let target = $(e.target).attr('href');
  router.navigate(target);
});
```

But the problem is, whenever I click on the image inside the `a`, I don't get the `href`, as it tries to get the `href` value from the image that I clicked on and not the `a`. However, if I click on the area surrounding the image, I get the `href` as desired.

**Attempts:**

I changed:

```
let target = $(e.target).attr('href');
```

To:

```
let target = $(this).attr('href');
```

But get absolutely nothing when clicking the image or the surrounding area!

What am I doing wrong? I can't believe I'm asking questions about simple things like this but I've just taken a year off coding and I'm obviously missing something important, and it's baffling me.

I want to be able to click *everything* inside the `a` and get the `href` of the `a`.

Comment: Maybe just write your code so that, if it detects the clicked item was the `<img>` rather than the `<a>`, it traverses up to the parent and _then_ gets the `href`?

Comment: excuse me but, what is "data-path" in the anchor declaration?

Comment: @Richard; `data-path` is a custom data attribute (http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [e.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), this will get the element that the event was bound to, e.target will get the element that was actually clicked.

Comment: I changed my selected answer to this one, as it deals with the actual issue. Using arrow functions is perfectly fine if not using `this` but all that was needed was to use `e.currentTarget` to make it work. Thanks you!

Comment: Yes, apologies I should have given an explanation. with es6 arrow functions the context of the "this" keyword remains in the outer scope so it's better to reference the event object instead. currentTarget is better to use as it returns the element object of what the event was bound where as target will return the inner element that was actually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main_nav a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let target = $(this).attr('href'); 
   alert(target)
});
```

See [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ask3a4gf/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it should be:

```
$(this).parent().attr('href');
```

Without using jquery this would be:

```
this.parentNode.getAttribute("href")
```

Complete code is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'image-class/id', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
 let target = $(this).parent().attr('href');
  router.navigate(target);
});
```

Image is child of anchor tag, you need to get his parent when you click on image so this done by this way.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ask3a4gf/

Answer (score 0):

Try : `var href = event.toElement.parentElement.href;`

Answer (score -2):

Your issue is coming from the use of an arrow function instead of `function(e)`

Change `(e) => {` to `function(e) {` and use `$(this).attr('href')`

Quoting from mozilla -

> An **[arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own **this**

Comment: Thanks very much! What is the reason behind this? I'm trying to write Javascript using the ES6 standard and using Babel to transpile, so I have many arrow functions in my script.

Comment: Don't confuse "wanting to use ES6" with "have to use arrow functions". Arrow functions are for when you need to preserve `this` context to the declaring context, they don't _replace_ `function() {}` notation in the slightest. jQuery will do some magic when using `function()` syntax so that `$(this)` does "the right thing", and it can't do that for arrow functions. That said, relying on that magic has become a progressively bad idea, because it subverts how you would expect JS to work based on the spec. Another option is to first find your `<a>`s and then bind clicks for each explicitly.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not familiar with Babel but I just know arrow functions don't have `this` keyword. So now when you call `e.target` you are getting the actual low level target of your click event. `this` keyword refers to the element this current function is working on, which in your case is `[data-path]`

Comment: Arrow functions absolute have `this`: unlike normal functions where it's implicit, in arrow functions `this` is explicitly bound to the declaring context, no matter when and where you invoke that arrow function. If the problem is `e.target`, then the simplest solution is using `e.currentTarget` as per digital-pollution's answer.